# Check 2 other objects for a collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When leaving a room, I'd like to check if objects are left in the right places. What would be the best way to do this?

I have a collider set up so it can tell if the correct object leaves or is put back, but I don't know how to check this when exiting. :(

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: To clarify, I'm looking how to check if a collider's been entered/exit that isn't attached to the game object.

Comment: Put a collider at the door. When it collides with the player, check for those things. Or maybe in the `Update` method of the player, you can check if the player is close to the door, if it's in the same place, then check for those things. That's basically a trigger.

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is how to check for those things.

Comment: You said you can tell if the objects are put back or not. What's the problem? Maybe clarify it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A way to check is to use the different Physics.Overlap methods such as Physics.OverlapSphere or Physics.OverlapBox. These methods checks and retrieves all collider within its radius/bounds by providing a center and a radius/size.

You can then iterate through to look whether the collider you want to check against is within the collider array the method returns.

Search result for all overlap methods in documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=Physics.Overlap